# AdapterNotSpecified when using establish_connection on ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

Here is an example model.

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
    establish_connection "other_db_#{Rails.env}"
end
```

And here is the database.yml file.

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3

other_db_development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/my_other_database_development.sqlite

other_db_production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/my_other_database_production.sqlite
```

When I try and access the model I get the following error:

**ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get this to work you need to change:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
    establish_connection "other_db_#{Rails.env}"
end
```

to

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
    establish_connection "other_db_#{Rails.env}".to_sym
end
```